# Flag management policy

Tags: discussion, flagging

Is there any mechanism to apply the correct decision to all flag of a question?

I flag this post:[Can an ATtiny print results to a console?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24930/can-an-attiny-print-results-to-a-console%20)  saying that it was better to be migrated to the arduino exchange. The flag was rejected by a  moderator X than fewer hours later the post was effectively migrated to Arduino exchange.  What is the management behind the flag, is it by the "feeling" of a moderator X that the flag is rejected or accepted? It is pretty inconsistent for the management of the forum that moderator X reject it than few hours later moderator Y migrated or close the question.

Should the decision of 1 moderator concerning a flag should be considered as the final decision to maintain consistency across the management of flag?

Comment: Speaking of this: Why don't they give more options for migration? Questions can only be moved to super user and EE.Meta

Comment: @laptop2d it's really based on manual migration stats. And considering how many incredibly bad/shortsighted migrations, and migrations of bad questions happen to (Arduino or RPI specifically), an automatic migration path isn't a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration policy is not a subject where the moderators agree. You get a flag resolution based on which moderator sees the flag in the queue.

Migration is something where the migrating mod makes a decision that cannot be easily undone or reviewed. If one moderator decides to migrate a question, it's gone.